# Cardinality of the union of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

I am having trouble attempting to prove the inequality $|X\cup Y| \le |X|+|Y|$.

Here is my intuitive argument when we take the union of $X\cup Y$ if there are repeated elements then they are not counted twice. However, the sum $|X|+|Y|$ counts all of the elements of $X$ and $Y$, as well as any repeated elements.

My problem lies in attempting to make this argument rigorous. Could someone please help me? Thank you.

Edit: I don't believe I can assume functions? Also, these sets are finite. I don't know if this helps clarify some things.

Comment: You don't assume functions. The standard definition of the cardinality of a finite set $A$ is the natural number $k$ such that there exists a bijective function from $\{1,2,3,..., k\}$ to $A$. What is the definition in your course?

Comment: Yeah I realize the standard definition. That's why I'm somewhat frustrated. I think the just define it as the number of elements in that set.

Comment: Well, if they don't give a sufficiently rigorous definition of "number of elements in the set", then you should be able to just say that the cardinality of a disjoint union of finite sets is equal to the sum of the cardinalities of the sets by noting that they don't share any elements so the elements aren't counted twice. But any teacher would surely accept the bijection definition and proof if you give it.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm never sure what to do when we are given somewhat loose definitions in courses. Sometimes I freeze up and it hurts me, or I try to prove it the rigorous way and it hurts me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need more details depending on what you can assume. But the sketch is like this.

Case 1: $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. So $|X\cup Y| = |X| + |Y|$.

Case 2: $X$ and $Y$ are not disjoint. Take $Z=Y\setminus X$. Then $|Z|<|Y|$ and $Z,X$ are disjoint. $|X\cup Z| = |Z| + |X| < |X| + |Y|$ using case 1 and the fact that $Z$ was constructed by removing elements from $Y$. We know that $Z \cup X = Y \cup X$, so $|X\cup Y| < |X| + |Y|$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fact that the cardinality of two disjoint finite sets is the sum of the cardinalities (not sure if you need the full rigorous proof using bijective functions for that, if you do, see below). Then consider $X \cup (Y\setminus{X})$.

http://planetmath.org/cardinalityofdisjointunionoffinitesets